# Remove 16GB Cap

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

My local computer shop installed Windows 7 Home Premium with their OEM key, and I cannot afford to upgrade to a higher version. I have 32GB of RAM but Home Premium has capped the RAM to 16GB, rendering half of my RAM unusable. Is there any way I can change a registry key or something to allow myself to remove the 16GB cap?

Comment: @Ramhound it's an [OEM](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/pages/index.aspx) key, it's quite legal.

Comment: You should elaborate on what led to them installing the "wrong" version of the OS for your hardware. They might owe you a refund, or a replacement, or something.

Comment: @Ramhound he says in a comment to an answer below that he got the license key sticker with it.

PS: there's nothing illegal in the US about *possessing* pirated media, just making and selling it. Don't scare this guy into thinking he might be breaking the law just because the computer shop might have done so.

Comment: @Sparr - If he has the sticker then he is fine.  I was trying to verify he had the sticker.  I posted my comment before the answer, since saying you have no options except piracy, is a horrible answer.  Furthermore I was accusing the shop not him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are your only options for Windows to be able to use all 32 GB of RAM.

1. Upgrade to Windows 7 Pro, it is $84-$99 to do so.
2. Upgrade to Windows 8, it is $119-$200 to do so.

If you do upgrade make sure you get 64 bit. You say you can't afford to upgrade, then I don't know why you bought 32 GB of RAM for a home version of Windows. If you can afford the RAM, you can afford the upgrade.

[Windows 8](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/cat/ThemeID.33363200/categoryID.62684800?tid=sGeBseCiq_dc&cid=5250&pcrid=19104934493&WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=pointitsem_Microsoft%20US_google_5%20-%20Windows%208&WT.source=google&WT.medium=cpc)

[Windows 7](http://www.discountmountainsoftware.com/miwi7pranupf.html?cmp=gpl&utm_source=googlepla&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=Microsoft%20Windows%207%20Professional%20Anytime%20Upgrade%20-%2032/64%20Bit%20%28from%20Windows%207%20Home%20Premium%29%20-%20DOWNLOAD%20ONLY&utm_campaign=googlepla&gclid=CLSWtqTYubgCFQ6f4AodOiYAmA)

[Memory Limits for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)

Comment: The 32GB RAM was cheap at time of purchase, around £30.

Comment: @JordanDoyle I have never seen RAM that cheap for that size in my life. What brand and type of RAM is it? Also was it used RAM?

Comment: I believe it was branded under Komputerbay on Amazon. I did a check on it (I believe it was called MEMTEST?) all the RAM was fine, none dead. DDR3, 12800, 9-9-9-24, 1600MHz I believe. I'm just copying this off Amazon. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Jordan likely purchased http://www.amazon.com/Komputerbay-PC3-10600-1333MHz-204-Pin-9-9-9-25/dp/B00698WPK0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1374173768&sr=8-1&keywords=Komputerbay+32GB+%284x+8GB%29 perhaps with a discount and an exchange rate it would be possible http://www.amazon.com/Komputerbay-PC3-10600-1333MHz-204-Pin-9-9-9-25/dp/B00698WPK0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1374173768&sr=8-1&keywords=Komputerbay+32GB+%284x+8GB%29

Answer (score 0):

Unless they gave you that OEM key itself (the sticker with the license number) they sold you a pirated copy of Windows.

There is not any way to circumvent the 16 GB cap, unless you go even further into software piracy territory.

Or install Linux. It's free and doesn't have these silly restrictions.

Comment: I have the sticker, yes. I'd rather not go trudging into piracy territory.

Comment: At least your Home Premium is legit then. Awesome price on that RAM. You would need to upgrade to Win7 Pro or Ultimate, or to Win8 Pro. In all cases the 64 bit version as 32 bit is limited to just 4 GB max. Honestly, unless you are using extremely RAM hungry software, you would hardly notice the difference between 16G and 32G. The unused 16G doesn't degrade the performance in your current setup.

Comment: Thanks Tonny, I'll look into having to buy Windows 7 Ultimate. Price is a bit steep though, I'm only seeing around £150.